# Why are there no parentheses after a named function when you use .on('click' ) or .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just found out, that `.on('click')` and `.click()` require a named function to be written without parentheses behind.

Like so

```
$('.close').click(close);
```

Why is that so? I guess I want the function to happen right away on click, that's where you usally omit the parentheses, when assigning a function to a variable!?!

When you use an anonymous function, the parentheses have to be there!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function is being passed as an argument.

If there were parentheses after it, it would be *called* and the return value would be passed as the argument.

> I want the function to happen right away on click

"right away" and "on click" are two very different times.

> When you use an anonymous function, the parentheses have to be there

The parentheses that form part of the function expression syntax do.

```
.click(function () { ... });
```

The ones that call the function must not.

```
.click(function () { ... }());
```

Comment: So the arguments of the named function are passed anyway?

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah, there are no parantheses on the anonymous function! Thanks.

Comment: You define what arguments a function will accept when you declare the function. The arguments it receives are determined by how the function is called (in this case it is called (on click) by a jQuery event handler wrapper so there will be one argument, which will be the event object).

Comment: Ok, so I have the event object plus the arguments from declaring the function? :/

Comment: You don't *get* arguments by declaring the function. That just determines that any arguments that are passed in are named. The event object is the argument that is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to pass the actual function as an argument (so jQuery can call it later, when the element is clicked), rather than *calling* the function and passing it's *return value* to the `.click()` (which isn't what you want, but is what would happen if you put the `()` after the function name).

Whatever function you pass as that first argument to `.click()` will be called when the element is clicked. It will always be called with one argument (the `Event` object, which you may or may not ignore depending on what needs to happen on click).

So you can do:

```
var close = function(evt) {
    // do stuff
};
$('.close').click(close);
```

Or

```
$('.close').click(function(evt) {
    // do stuff, anonymous function
});
```

Either way, you do NOT put `()` after it, because you do **not** want to *call* the function when you first apply it as the element's click handler. You want to let jQuery call it *later on*, when a click occurs. jQuery will do this by passing whatever arguments it wants (which we know will be 1 Event object).

---

To put it another way: the brackets immediately after the word `function`:

```
function(arg1, arg2)
```

always say what arguments you expect to receive.

The brackets after a function's name:

```
close(arg1, arg2)
```

would mean you want to **call** that function, passing in those arguments. This second one should never occur in this particular code, because **you never call `close`**. jQuery does (when the element is clicked).

Comment: So I cannot have additional arguments on these functions?

Comment: @dollarvar Not as standard, no. There *are* ways to do so, but there are actually *very* few situations when you would need to. If, within your click handler function, you need to refer to variables that are in scope when the function was defined, you can just refer to them within your click handler function (as JS will have created a closure, so you can just refer to the variables as normal). And if you need to refer to things relating to the actual element being clicked, you can just use `$(this)` to refer to the element, and get whatever you need from it.

Comment: (should probably clarify re the closures, you'd need to wrap the function within another function to create that closure if you wanted to refer to variables in scope which may change value later)